# jQuery fade and change src

Tags: jquery, image, fade, src

I have and arrow png for my site, and I would like a different colored arrow to appear when hovering above the arrow. I know how to do that, but what I would like to know is if I can create a fade effect between the 2 arrows, even though i display the new arrow by changing the src of the original one.

Comment: i tried googeling a solution, so im open to any suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can!

```
$("a.arrow").fadeOut(1000, function(){
   $(this).find("img").attr("src", "newurl");
   $(this).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

[**See Demo - Standard**](http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/PLwam/)

[**See Demo - Images overlayed**](http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/PLwam/1/)

Comment: `a` is your anchor link. `arrow` is a class I added. Making a jsfiddle to show

Comment: `.fadeout()`'s syntax is `.fadeout(duration,callback` not `.fadeout(callback,duration` [Ref](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

Comment: Thanks for the example! is it possible to fade the pictures without seeing the background on change? that was my initial question

Comment: @guyzyl What background? Which elements background?

Comment: I meant fade a picture to the picture, without seeing white in the middle of the fading

Comment: @guyzyl Ah I see, thats exactly perhaps a bit simplier lol. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/PLwam/1/

Comment: @Curt - THANK YOU! thats what I wanted :), can you add comments so I can better understand it?

Comment: @guyzyl Google "jQuery hover", "jQuery find", "jQuery fadeToggle" "Css position absolute"

Comment: is it possible to do that without stacking the images?

Comment: No I don't believe so. You can have 1 `img` element with 2 `src`